# Print out wall time for qsub job

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub

I am currently running jobs on a cluster with qsub and have imposed a wall time of 10 hours on the jobs. Sometimes jobs exceed this time and are therefore terminated, and sometimes jobs are terminated for other reasons. Either way, I would like to have a footer at the bottom of the qsub log file which would indicate when the job terminated (optionally with the status code indicating whether it completed successfully or got interrupted) and the total wall time. Putting something like:

```
date
command here
date
```

in the qsub file wouldn't work since the last `date` won't get executed if the job goes over time. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `qacct`  command should give you that information. From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qacct):

> The qacct utility scans the accounting data file (see accounting(5))
>   and produces a summary of information for wall-clock time, cpu-time,
>   and system time

Otherwise, if you really need the information to be in the output file, you can try something like

```
trap "date; exit 2" 2 3 15
```

in your script so that the `date` command is executed whenever the script is terminated.

Comment: Thanks, I can output the $JOB_ID at the start of the job, then use ``qacct`` later.